# How to open html file created by gmplot in streamlit

Tags: python-3.x, streamlit, gmplot

I have tried multiple ways to embed the HTML file in Streamlit but it is only showing the empty white background. I have tried to use `streamlit.v1.components` but nothing works.

```
import streamlit as st

with open("maps.html", "r") as file:
    html_content = file.read()


st.components.v1.html(html_content, height=600, scrolling=True)
```

This is not working